# How do I split a file on a delimiter that is on its own line?

Tags: perl

I have the following file:

```
some data
some data 1
some data 1
hostname = abc
some data
some data 1
some data 1
some data
some data 1
some data 1
hostname = xyz
some data
some data 1
some data 1
some data
some data 1
some data 1
hostname = pqr
some data
some data 1
some data 1
some data
some data 1
some data 1
```

How can I extract the lines between two hostname line entries using Perl?

Comment: I guess this is one of those rare cases when you really wish that $/ could be set to a regex :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slurp the whole thing into a string, `$string`, and do something like this:

```
$string =~ /hostname = abc\n(.*)hostname = xyz\n/s;
```

The lines between the `abc` and `xyz` hostname lines will be in `$1` after that.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
#!perl -w
my @someArray;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/hostname.*/) {
        print @someArray;
        @someArray = ();
    }
    else {
        push (@someArray, $_);
    }
}

__DATA__
some data
some data 1
some data 1
hostname = abc
some data
some data 1
some data 1
some data
some data 1
some data 1
hostname = xyz
some data
some data 1
some data 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -nle'/hostname = abc/../hostname = xyz/&&print' datafile
```

Comment: this only prints entries for hostname.

Comment: The flipflop operator has lower precedence than &&. You probably want to use `and` instead.

Comment: @Avinash: Try what I suggested. If I'm right, the `&& print` is being tacked onto the right-hand-side check.

Answer (score 0):

[`split`](http://p3rl.org/split) indeed suffices, just give it the right pattern.

```
use DDS; Dump split /hostname = .*\n/, 'some data
some data 1
some data 1
hostname = abc
some data
some data 1
some data 1
some data
some data 1
some data 1
hostname = xyz
some data
some data 1
some data 1
some data
some data 1
some data 1
hostname = pqr
some data
some data 1
some data 1
some data
some data 1
some data 1';
```

output

```
$VAR1 = "some data\nsome data 1\nsome data 1\n";
$VAR2 = "some data\nsome data 1\nsome data 1\nsome data\nsome data 1\nsome data 1\n";
$VAR3 = "some data\nsome data 1\nsome data 1\nsome data\nsome data 1\nsome data 1\n";
$VAR4 = "some data\nsome data 1\nsome data 1\nsome data\nsome data 1\nsome data 1";
```